# How vue can read a js file from node

Tags: node.js, vue.js, configuration, vue-cli

I am using node 10.16.0 and vue 2.6.11 and I want to have a config.js file in the node root folder, pointing to a folder that is outside the node structure

```
hello
   hi.txt
node-project //node project
   server.js
   config.js 
   public //contains build vue
   vue-project //contains not build vue
```

config.js should contain something like

```
let txtFile= '../hello/hi.txt'; 
exports.txtFile = txtFile;
```

I want to be able to keep the config.js file in node, not blended in vue, but have build vue (inside public folder) also able to read it

Ideally I would like to read config.js from vue-project and when I do `npm run build` , I can also read config.js from public (where I put the builded vue project)

Here is my failed, over-complicated attempt

Since everything you put in the public folder of a vue project it gets passed to the build, and the path changes automatically during build, I did this

```
hello
   hi.txt
node-project //node project
   server.js  
   vue-project //contains not build vue
      public
         configs
             config.js //contains ../../../../hello/hi.txt
      src
        views
           Home.vue //imports configs/config.js
```

and when I did `npm run build` the above becomes

```
hello
   hi.txt
node-project //node project
   server.js 
   public //contains build vue
      css
      js
      fonts
      configs
         config.js
      index.html
```

So the config.js automatically transfered to the build vue, the path to config.js is automatically changed and the config.js is in the node, easily accessible, only one sub-folder away, not blended in the vue js.

The problem is that now config.js changed position, so I have to manually change its content to
`let txtFile= '../../hello/hi.txt';`

I thought that its alright, small price to pay, its just a single manual change.

But the problem is that Vue does not read the changed value. Its still reads `../../../../hello/hi.txt` and not `'../../hello/hi.txt` . Restarting node does not help. I guess vue caches the value?

Please advice. I hope my example helped you understand what I want to do. Feel free to ask me anything that will help you clarify

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to have the contents loaded at compile-time (baked in) or run-time? Seems like you're trying to do it compile-time, but the choice to have it in the `public` folder seems contrary to that.

Comment: @Daniel OK, you have a point. But I want the `config.js` to be in node , so its easily accesible and editable by other devs, not having to touch Vue. So, what should I do ?